# draggable after load from txt file

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div board with draggable items.

on save I export the content of the div board to a txt file.

the txt file contains something like:

```
<div class="ui-draggable sleep ui-resizable" style="position: absolute; left: 450px; top: 117px;">

<img src="/media/img/badkamer/1361540973Duravit2ndFloor.jpg" class="center">

<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>

<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>

<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
```

so basically its a image in a div which is draggable and resizable.

but when I load it I see the image to resize the div, but I can't drag or resize the image.

I get the txt file with:

```
<script
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#bord").load("/media/moodboards/1.txt");
        $(".sleep").draggable();       
});
</script>
```

but my problem is I can't drag or resize the div sleep.

can some one help me I found a lot of other topics but none was working for me.

Everything looks good but the functions don't work (resize and drag)

Can some one help me making these functions work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly try to call it after the load:

```
$("#bord").load("/media/moodboards/1.txt", function() {
    $(".sleep").draggable();
});
```

If that doesn't work please create a small fiddle.

Comment: Thx haha such a small thing such a diffrence ! Voted as solution